# keyboard stuck when searching in uitableview using uisearchbar...?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a uitableview and uisearchbar. I'm binding table with tons of records and give functionality to user can search from that. But many times when data size is large keyboard stuck uptill it reload the table. Is it anyway so I can asynchronously search. It's iOS 4 app.

[image]

my uisearchbar textDidChange method is as below

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
if(searchText.length == 0)
{
    isFiltered = FALSE;
}
else
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        isFiltered = true;
        membersMFilterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int lineCount = [[[membersMArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"LineCount"] intValue];
        NSString *membersMArrayValue;
        for (int i=0; i<[membersMArray count]; i++)
        {
            membersMArrayValue = [membersMArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *line;
            for (int j=0; j<lineCount; j++)
            {
                line = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Line%d",j+1];
                NSRange lineRange = [[membersMArrayValue valueForKey:line] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
                if(lineRange.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    [membersMFilterArray addObject:[membersMArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

[tblMember reloadData];}
```

my array is as below from which I've search, Actually this is one user data which arrise in one table row and if there is 10000 rows then multiply with this. So above for loop is I think as because of this way.

```
(
    {
    Line1 = "Ashish";
    Line10 = "Ahmedabad";
    Line11 = "Gujarat";
    Line12 = "";
    Line13 = "India";
    Line14 = "";
    Line15 = "";
    Line16 = "abc@yahoo.com";
    Line17 = "";
    Line18 = "";
    Line19 = "xyz";
    Line2 = "Ahmedabad, Gujarat";
    Line20 = "Jun 04, 2012";
    Line3 = "";
    Line4 = "";
    Line5 = "";
    Line6 = "abc";
    Line7 = "xyz";
    Line8 = "";
    Line9 = "";
    LineCount = 20;
    "Member_id" = GM00018004;
    RowNo = 01;
}
```

)

Comment: share the searching code..or did you tested in real device? if the issue found in simulator, It may be your system performance issue.

Comment: simulator work faster than device in my situation,I've i5 processor in my mac.Provided screenshot is from device.

Comment: @Deer: have you got your answer?. i am also facing same problem while searching. please share your experience with me.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. You can perform the search asynchronously, say, with [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html). You can then notify the datasource of your table view to update.

However, it would be much better to make your search more efficient and achieve acceptable real time updates. How to achieve this, depends on how your data is stored and indexed. For example, if you are using Core Data you would have to tweak your NSFetchedResultsController and maybe construct a new entity with single strings of words occurring in your longer strings to be searched.

Looking at your search code, you have two nested loops - an almost certain recipe for performance degradation. Maybe you should consider some of Apple's automatic iteration mechanisms, (there are still iterations, but behind the scenes) such as with key paths or predicates. For instance, something like:

```
resultArray = [membersArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText]];
```

Comment: No, I'm not using coredata. All data come from webservice output and I store them in my nsarray. And then search from it.

Comment: Hello mundi, I already go with predicate but it was not help me, that's why I moved to above looping thing.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, i think the **two for loops are unnecessary**. Use better concept to sort the array items.

Some suggestions from my part to speedup.

```
Remove the auto-release-pool     
Use one for-loop instead of two
```

You can check it out the **start & end time of execution** using NSlog.Discover the time taken process and fix it.

**Example:**

```
NSLog(@"loop1 started now")
for (int i=0; i<[membersMArray count]; i++)
        {
            membersMArrayValue = [membersMArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *line;
            for (int j=0; j<lineCount; j++)
            {

                NSLog(@"loop2 started now")
                line = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Line%d",j+1];
                NSRange lineRange = [[membersMArrayValue valueForKey:line] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
                if(lineRange.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    [membersMFilterArray addObject:[membersMArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                    break;
                }
            }  

         NSLog(@"loop2 ended now")
        }

NSLog(@"loop1 ended now")
```

Comment: Hello, Ramshad, Plz check my post with array which I updated. And I think I have to go through two loops for that.