# Keyboard stuck when search in tableview using searchdisplaycontroller swift2

Tags: swift2, ios9, uisearchcontroller

when i type any character or words then keyboard stuck for some time

here is code

```
  func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    menuView.hidden = true
    searchStr = searchController.searchBar.text
    temp = 1

    if searchStr != ""
    {
      calledYoutubeAPI()
    }
    else
    {
      flag = 11
      noticeView.removeFromSuperview()
      tableView.reloadData()
    }

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchStr)
    let arr = (videoName as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    self.videoName = arr as! [String]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
}


    func searchBar_Intialization()
{

    if flag == 0
    {
        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.resultSearchController.delegate = self
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Youtube & Library"
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
        //self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

here is similar question  [keyboard stuck when searching in uitableview using uisearchbar...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304425/keyboard-stuck-when-searching-in-uitableview-using-uisearchbar)

Comment: you are using UIsearchController not search display controller!!!!!

Comment: why are you reloading data on main thread at one place and not at other palce?

Comment: when i remove dispatch_async then problem not solved

Comment: remove the code in else condition else, move the last 4 lines of code to the else block and remove the reload data call in else block

Comment: try this but not work

Comment: show how you are dealing with keyboard. PLease post the code regarding the searchbar and keyboard

Comment: how you initialised you search bar and where did you make it first responder?